# Creating a dictionary within an If-Statement

Tags: python, csv

I've just recently learned about dictionaries and I'm trying to create a function that adds a gaming genre to an empty dictionary that is tied to a specific gaming publisher that the user requests from info pulled from a CSV:

```
with open("vgsales.csv") as text_file:
  gaming_sales = text_file.readlines()

publisher = input ("Which publisher are you interested in: ")
print()

count = 0

    genre_dict = {}

    for info in gaming_sales[0:100]:
        pieces = info.strip().split(",")
            
        if pieces[5] == publisher:
            count += 1

        elif pieces[4] in genre_dict.keys():
            genre_dict[pieces[4]] += 1

        else:
            genre_dict[pieces[4]] = 1 

    print(genre_dict)  

    return print(f"{publisher} appears {count} time(s) within the top 100 in Global Sales with the genre(s): {genre_dict.get(publisher)}.")
```

Basically, I want the print statement to look like "Nintendo appears 52 times within the top 100 in Global Sales with the genre(s): Shooter: 4, Roleplaying: 15" etc., etc.

But I just can't seem to get it to work right. The count part works, but not the dictionary. I'm not sure if I'm correctly tying the publisher to the pulled genre.

Note: I'm unable to use pandas for this project.

Data Sample as Requested:

```
15,Wii Fit Plus,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,9.09,8.59,2.53,1.79,22
16,Kinect Adventures!,X360,2010,Misc,Microsoft Game Studios,14.97,4.94,0.24,1.67,21.82
17,Grand Theft Auto V,PS3,2013,Action,Take-Two Interactive,7.01,9.27,0.97,4.14,21.4
```

Comment: can you add a data sample so I can advice on the code, 1 or 2 lines would be nice.

Comment: Added 3 lines from the dataset at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A closing parantheses() is missing after publisher in print statement

Comment: I forgot to add that when typing it in here, but it's there in the original code. Added it for clarity.

Comment: Your elif and else blocks never get executed when a valid publisher is entered and therefore no data is appended in the dictionary. Replace the elif with if and then it works.

I tried it and the output is

`Which publisher are you interested in: Nintendo

{'Sports': 1, 'Platform': 1, 'Racing': 1}
Nintendo appears 3 time(s) within the top 100 in Global Sales with the genre(s): None.`

Comment: But the return statement is ending with None though. What I'm trying to get to happen is for the genres tied to the publisher to appear in the return statement.

For example:
Nintendo appears 3 time(s) within the top 100 in Global Sales with the genre(s): {'Sports': 1, 'Platform': 1, 'Racing': 1}

Comment: Then instead of printing `{genre_dict.get(publisher)}` print `{genre_dict}`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but when the dataset hits something other than Nintendo (sorry, should have added that to the question. First time posting.) it'll add that to the dictionary as well, and then the printed data is skewed.

EX (Changed the provided dataset lines to ones other than Nintendo):

Will print out: Microsoft Game Studios appears 1 time(s) within the top 100 in Global Sales with the genre(s): {'Misc': 1, 'Action': 1, 'Platform': 1}.

So now {genre_dict} is reading/returning everything in the dictionary rather than just the genre that's tied to MGS which is Misc.